# How to sub-string first word in a given line

Tags: scala

Version scala 2.10.+

I have an address

```
 420 Bedok North aveneu 2
```

All that I need is to extract

```
420
```

Out of the given line. How to get it?

Comment: var reg = "(\\d)*".r;   regx.findPrefixOf("420 Bedok North aveneu 2").get.....     It worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val address = "420 Bedok North aveneu 2"
address.takeWhile(_ != ' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val address = "420 Bedok North aveneu 2"
address.split(" ").head
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = '420 Bedok North aveneu 2';
var newStr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {
    if (str.substring(i, i+1) == ' ') {
      break;
    } else {
       newStr += str.substring(i, i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `(("",true) /: s) { case ((n,b),c) if b && c.isDigit => (n+c, true) case ((n,_),_) => (n, false) }._1`